# Comparing CGPoint and image center property

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uiimage, cgpoint

I could really do with some help here. I've spent the past couple of hours trying to work out how to compare the value of a CGPoint and the center property of an image. I had assumed the two values were in the form of x and y coordinates. Below is the code i have written.

```
-(void) jigsawCompleted:(CGPoint) newcenter {

if(image1.center == newcenter &&
   image2.center == newcenter &&
   image3.center == newcenter &&
   image4.center == newcenter) {
    NSLog(@"success");

}
}
.......
.......
//if current touch is inside the rectangle
if (CGRectContainsPoint(snapToRect, location)) {
    touch.view.alpha = 1.0;
    //make a point with the coords below
    CGPoint newcenter = CGPointMake(78, 382);
    //assign the center coords of the current touch to this newly created point
    touch.view.center = newcenter;
    [self jigsawCompleted:newcenter];
    return;
} else {
    touch.view.alpha = 0.3;
}
```

When comparing the two values in the jigsawCompleted method i get the error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGpoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'CGPoint').

Any help please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`CGPointEqualToPoint()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointEqualToPoint).

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(image1.center, newCenter) && ...)
```

Answer (score 3):

The point is a struct that includes x and y.  Use CGPointEqualToPoint.  To compare if a point equals an image center:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(image1.center, newcenter) { ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `CGPointEqualToPoint`:

```
if (CGPointEqualToPoint(image1.center, newCenter) &&
    CGPointEqualToPoint(image2.center, newCenter) &&
    CGPointEqualToPoint(image3.center, newCenter) &&
    CGPointEqualToPoint(image4.center, newCenter)) {
// ...
```